# c++ Where is the issue with this question? (constructors with parameters)

Tags: c++

**Assume that string class has private data members as the following:**

```
char *strval; 
int length;
```

**Is the following constructor code for string class correct? If it is not correct, why?**

```
string::string(const char* s):length(strlen(s)) 
{ 
strval = s; 
}
```

<strike>My answer was that strlen() is evaluating a pointer value, but that sounds wrong.</strike>

Comment: Impossible to tell without more information. Your answer is wrong, however.

Comment: strlen always evaluates a pointer value. It starts at the pointed-to memory address and reads up to "\0", the null terminator, then returns the length of the string.

Comment: What do you think happens if s == NULL ?

Comment: @Paul Maybe his class is documented such that s being NULL is undefined?

Answer (score 7):

The constructor code given is *correct*, in that it will compile and run successfully for most inputs. However, it is poor style for at least a couple of reasons:

- One member is initialised with the initialiser list, while the other is assigned within the constructor (this is inconsistent)
- No check is made whether `s` is `NULL` or not (but this could be documented as illegal input)
- If you're not making a copy of the string, it's redundant to store both the *pointer* and the *length* independently (because they could get out of sync)

Comment: That's what I thought. It's completely correct, but the given answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The code is not correct, and this won't even compile. `strval=s` will fail because `strval` is a pointer to `const`, and `s` is not. The following is a better place to start from:

```
class string
{
    const char *strval; // This must be const for 'strval = s' to work.
    int length;
    string (const char *s);
};

string::string(const char* s):length(strlen(s)) 
{ 
    strval = s; 
}
```

@Greg 's points still stand. I'm just highlighting one major point.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways the string might reasonably work, but as presented it doesn't fall into any of the three categories.  They are:

1. a "value-semantic" object that
   copies the specified data and
   maintains ownership of it, just as
   `std::string` does
2. a `(const char*, length)` const
   "reference" to some text owned by
   the caller, which guarantees that
   text's lifetime will be longer than
   the "string"'s usage
3. a `(char *, length)` reference to
   a writeable buffer owned by the
   caller, but into which the "string"
   object may make updates (perhaps
   even moving the NUL terminator)

We can consider each in turn.

### 1. value semantics as per `std::string`

The question very explicitly states that this is a "string" class, and that implies (weakly, but we don't have a lot to go...) the class is intended as a general purpose value-semantic string.  Assuming for the moment that's true, we can consider the implementation presented: the class simply remembers the address and length of a non-const character buffer specified by the caller without taking ownership of the buffer.  Even if from the caller's perspective the string class is being given ownership of that buffer (i.e. the caller won't further modify the content without going through the string API), there's no evidence that the string object has the means to grow the buffer, which is a basic requirement of a general purpose string class.

So, if it's a general purpose string, then it should instead make a copy of the value and take ownership.  That's best done by re-arranging the data members to:

```
int length;  // should really be size_t
char *strval;
```

...so that the constructor can use the initialisation list and know the value of length will be populated first, and therefore usable in the initialisation of strval - this removes the need to calculate the string length twice...

```
string(const char* p, int n)
  : length(strlen(p)), strval(new char[length + 1])
{
    strcpy(strval, p);
}
```

### 2. Constant reference to text

If the string is **not** meant to be a general purpose string, then the first and biggest issue with it is the name "string".  To work out a better name, let's return to the functionality presented.  It remembers the address and current-content-length of a caller-specified buffer: in my experience, that's most often done when the pointer is constant - for example, abstracting non-NUL-terminated substrings within the caller's character buffer - for example, element positions in a memory-mapped file.

The second issue - spotted first by Aaron - becomes that the constructor's string parameter is `const`, and would need to be changed to simply `char*` to allow `strval` to be initialised therefrom.  Alternatively, if you change `strval` to `const char*` we return to the `const` non-NUL-terminated substring reference that I mentioned finding useful above.  Again, an appropriate name should be found, e.g. `text_reference`, `substring_reader` or whatever works for you.

### 3. Non-constant reference to text

The `strval` pointer as presented is not `const`, which suggests an object with the ability to overwrite the provided buffer's content, but still doesn't have the ability to lengthen the buffer.  This is rarely useful in my experience, though it may be ideal for some particular program's needs.  A better name for such a class should be found, not easy!, but for example "buffer_overwriter" hints - to my mind at least - at the length-capped nature and non-`const` access.  Further, the provided constructor only works with already NUL-terminated buffers, but we can imagine a second constructor `(char*, int)` that removes that requirement and may make the object more widely useful.

Otherwise, Greg covers the ground very thoroughly.